# Selenium Code (CUCUMBER) not getting executed on Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd

When I run my Cucumber test runner file on Intellij IDEA,
I am not able to see any output on the console except the message "Process finished with exit code 0".
The actual code will not run can anyone please help me?

[image]

mvn test error:
[image: mvn test error]

Project structure:
[image: Project structure]

Entire Screenshot:
[image: Entire Screenshot]

Comment: What if you run the test with `mvn test` command?

Comment: @AlexeyR.
It was working fine before all of sudden it stopped working...
any idea why is this happening?

Comment: can you run with `mvn test` and publish the output?

Comment: @AlexeyR.,I run the same with mvn test and i am getting  the below error
**"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file or directory: D:\My Data\IntelliJ Projects\Maven_QC\feature"**

you can check the above screen shot named as  "mvn test error"

Comment: @AlexeyR. i have even attached the directory structure above please refer the screen shot named "Project structure"
please help me!!

Comment: @AlexeyR. Thanks for your response,
i have followed you suggestions and now i am getting **Process finished with exit code 0** on my console....my selenium code is not getting executed (ex. Opening the browser,Navigating to the website,take screenshot)..Please see my entire directory setup and console window in the above screenshot named "Entire screenshot"

Comment: @AlexeyR. As i am new to intellij i am just clicking on "run" on the IDE,is there any specific option called "run as Junit" on Intelij?

Answer (score 1):

There are several places to fix in your project:

- Better to keep your test runner and step definitions in `tests` but not in `main`
- Folder that contains feature files, package where your test runner is located and package where your step definition files are located have to match in a certain way:

  - If your test runner is in package `my.test.package` then your step definition code has to be placed either in `my.test.package` or to the sub-packages
  - If your test runner is in package `my.test.package` then your feature files have to be placed to the folder `resources/my/test/package` or sub-folders.